# php-cgi environment variable setup

Tags: php, c++, post, webserver, cgi

I'm building a small web server in C++, and I'm trying to add support for POST requests for PHP pages at the moment.

However, I don't know how I should pass the POST request body to the PHP executable. I've seen some examples where environment variables are set and `php-cgi` is called, but I haven't seen a definitive list of when to set which variables.

If I have the POST body data in a string, what's the best way of executing a POST request on the required PHP file using `php-cgi`? My setup works for PHP files where no arguments or POST data is sent from the web server to the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using the following environment variables:

```
cmd = "echo \""+req->body()+"\" | "
      "REDIRECT_STATUS=CGI "
      "REQUEST_METHOD=POST "
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME="+uri->src()+" "
      "CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded "
      "CONTENT_LENGTH="+std::to_string(req->body().length())+" "
      "php-cgi";
```